# Prove or disprove an equation with definite integrals.

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals

Please help me with this, I tried induction but didn't succeed. I really have no idea what else to try.

Prove or refute the equation(m and n can be any natural number):

\begin{array}{cc}
\int_{0}^{1} \ x^m (1-x)^n\,dx = \int_{0}^{1}\ x^n (1-x)^m\,dx \\
\end{array}

Comment: It's the same trick as a standard text book example/exercise of proving$$\int_0^a f(x) \, dx = \int_0^a f(a-x) \, dx$$ It can be verified by letting $u=a-x$.

Comment: Duplicate of http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2132500/prove-that-int-01xa-left1-x-rightbdx-int-01xb-left1-x-right

Answer (score 2):

Just consider the substitution $s=1-x$ to see that the equation holds.

Comment: It really worked. It was much easier than I thought. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Use integration by substitution: let $1-x=t$.
\begin{align*}
\int_0^1 x^m(1-x)^ndx&=-\int_1^0 (1-t)^mt^ndt\\
&=\int_0^1 (1-t)^mt^ndt\\
&=\int_0^1 (1-x)^mx^ndx
\end{align*}